# Google play interface

Tags: android, interface

I am trying to design an interface similar to google play. I am currently using a list view to display the images, I have tried example from http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html, but it displays only one image per row, I need multiple images on a row like on Google Play.

Any suggestions on what components to use? Is the list view the best option?

Note that the images will be lazy loaded and my interface needs to scroll vertically.

Thanks,
Kevin

Answer (score 2):

Try to use GridView : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

Some tutorial: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-gridview-layout-tutorial/